# JGraphT not using Name/Label providers in export

Tags: java, jgrapht

I have a custom class that drives my vertex.  That class implements an interface that provides the `JGraphT.export()` method the appropriate methods required for obtaining the vertexId and vertexLabel.  However, when I go to export my graphs to .dot files, I get errors: 
`Generated id 'Id: 1'for vertex 'ID: 1   Name: SystemServer  FQDN: SystemServer  Type: aidl' is not valid with respect to the .dot language`

This output is from the vertex class' toString() method and not the `getVertexId()` method exposed by my interface.  I don't really understand why it isn't using what I'm asking it to use.  You can see, from the code below how my code is structured.

```
public class JVertex implements IJGraph {
    int mId;
    String mName;
    // There are quite a bit more fields, but aren't relevant to the problem
    public JVertex(int i, String n) {
        mId = i;
        mName = n;
    }

    // Implemented from the IJGraph interface
    public String getVertexId() {
        return String.format("Id: %d", mId);
    }

    // Implemented from the IJGraph interface
    public String getVertexLabel() {
        return String.format("%s", getFQDN());
    }

    // You can infer what each of the excluded fields/methods from the String.format call
    public String toString() {
        String res = String.format("ID: %d Name: %s FQDN: %s Type: %s", mId, mName, getFQDN(), mType);

        return res;
    }
    /**
     *  There are quite a few more methods in this class, but they aren't relevant to the problem
     */
}

public class Main {
    static AbstractBaseGraph<V, DefaultEdge> mGraph;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        mGraph = new DefaultDirectedGraph<JVertex, DefaultEdge>(DefaultEdge.class);

        JVertex a, b;
        a = new JVertex(1, "test");
        b = new JVertex(2, "test2");
        mGraph.addVertex(a);
        mGraph.addVertex(b);
        mGraph.addEdge(a, b);

        // Defines the vertex id to be displayed in the .gv file
        IntegerNameProvider<JVertex> vertexId = new IntegerNameProvider<JVertex>(){
            public String getVertexName(JVertex p) {
                return p.getVertexId();
            }
        };
        // Defines the vertex label to be displayed in the .gv file
        StringNameProvider<JVertex> vertexLabel = new StringNameProvider<JVertex>(){
            public String getVertexName(JVertex p) {
                return p.getVertexLabel();
            }
        };
        // Just us a default edge label
        EdgeNameProvider<String> edgeLabel = new StringEdgeNameProvider<String>();

        // files the dotexporter
        DOTExporter<JVertex, DefaultEdge> dot = new DOTExporter(vertexId, vertexLabel, edgeLabel, null, null);
        try {
            dot.export(new FileWriter("path/to/output/file" + ".gv"), mGraph);
        } catch(IOException e) {
            System.err.println(e.toString());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Dang it!  I figured it out. It was the lowly ":".  Shame on me for missing it when reading: http://www.graphviz.org/content/dot-language, though they don't explicitly state that the ":" is off limits.